# oauth2 authorization with 3.0.5 spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am a spring security newbie. Is it possible to use oauth2 authorization with spring security 3.0.5? I need to implement resource owner password flow.

I am asking this because example `sparklr` uses `authentication-manager-ref` attribute in `http` node which is not present in spring security 3.0.5.

Thanks

Comment: Pls check this whether it helps you https://code.google.com/p/spring-security-social/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the 3.0.5 version of spring-security. I am using 3.1.3.RELEASE and haven't encountered any problem so far.